# Is this code generating memory leaks or is it clean?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I would like to know the best way to determine if the following code is generating memory leaks, as I understand that you have to free the memory when you are done using it, but in the same time this array or pointer to int is out of scope when the function return then it does not matter if I release it or not?

But in this particular case I cannot release the memory without interrupting the heap atleast according to microsoft debugger in Visual studio 2010.

And for learning how to best approach this could you please describe your ways of checking for memory leaks.

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int sieve(int n)
{
  int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  int max = floor(sqrt((double)n));
  int p = 2;
  memset(a,0,sizeof(int) * n);
  while(p<=max)
  {
    for(int i = 2 * p; i <= n; i+= p)
      a[i] = 1;
    while(a[++p]) /* Empty */ ;
  }
  while(a[n]) n--;
  /* free(a); */ // free our array as we are done with it. but it generate a heap error
  return n;
}
int main(void)
{
  cout << sieve(100) << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have out of bounds access, hence probably your freeing error

Comment: no time to debug this for you, but valgrind says there's a memory read/write error

Comment: You might want to look at `alloca` - http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/alloca.3.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are memory leaks in your program as you are not freeing the memory allocated.
use "free" here as you have used malloc and incase if you plan on using "new" then use "delete" operator
try to free memory before return statement.
you can also use the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool to find out the memory leaks in your program
check this [url](http://valgrind.org/) for more information.

this tool will help you to find out memory leaks in your programme.

Comment: I will thank you as you answer my question with the tools to further lean more and this goes out to all, I know that the above example is bad and include c++ and pure C and it could just as well be written in pure C but it was a fast test to see if I understood most of it.

Answer (score 3):

This line might be the cause of your error:

```
for(int i = 2 * p; i <= n; i+= p)
```

Here you loop while `i` is smaller *or equal* to `n`. But as all arrays the index must go from 0 to (size - 1). You should allocate one extra entry for the array:

```
int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your program as it stands will leak memory.

In general, if you are allocating memory dynamically (using `malloc` in C, or `new` in C++), and you aren't using smart pointers, you need to free the memory using `free` or `delete` respectively.

In your particular test program, it exits immediately after calling the `sieve()` method which means the allocated memory will automatically be deallocated by the operating system.

Also note that you seem to be writing `C` code in `C++`:

- `malloc` is the C way to allocate memory.  If you must use raw pointers, you should use `new` in C++ instead.
- Even better, use standard library containers like `vector` which will automatically manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 1):

More important things:

You allocated `n` int with `int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`. If you want to access this information, you must begin in `0` till `n-1`. In line `while(a[n]) n--;` you are out of bounds of your allocated memory section. Maybe a core !!!!

And, what happens if all `a[n]` values are 0 different? you decrease `n` until arrive to negative values. What about this? You access to `a[n]` values with `n < 0`. Maybe another core.

Remember, this is C / C++. It executes all you write, so be carefull !!!

General programming techniques:

- Verify all array limits.
- Verify `malloc` return values.
- Always `free` or `delete` your pointers
- Use correct types: `n` maybe be `unsigned`, use it!!

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating `n` ints, indexed from `0` to `n-1`. However, you are looping from 4 to `n` inclusive, meaning that you will assign index `n` and corrupt memory. That's why the `free` is causing an error (it checks for corruption when you call it).

You have to fix your memory corruption, then put back the `free` call.